# Testing Data grid

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I want to test the functionality of changing page size using RTL and enzyme. I wrote the test case but it's not working. I think the modal is not getting opened when I am triggering the click. This is the test case that I wrote. I have also attached the

```
describe('Datagrid',() => {
    it('change page size', async () => {
        render(<DataGridDemo />)
        const reqbtn = await screen.findByRole('button', {
            name: /rows per page: 5/i
        })
        await act(async ()=> {
            await fireEvent.click(reqbtn)

        })
        const modal = await screen.findByRole('presentation')
        console.log(prettyDOM(modal))
        fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('option', { name: /10/i }))
    })
})
```

[image]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/testcases-8gwxxo?file=/src/index.test.js)

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @CathalMacDonnacha yes getting the error that can find a role of presentation.